# Push Viewcontroller from within other ViewControllers that are not on top of Navstack?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol, touchesbegan

i have a scrollview loaded into my mainview (with pagecontrol). What i want to do is to have the scrollview use the "Touchesbegan" method to look for double taps and then have it push a new viewcontroller onto the navstack. The second goal seems impossible.

I have the seperated scrollviewcontroller call a method in the mainviewcontroller. That method should push a new viewcontroller onto the stack. It doesnt, but when i call this method from within the mainviewcontrollerclass it does work?!

in the scrollviewcontroller class:

```
MainViewController *mvcC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mvcC loadMapView];
[mvcC release];
```

in the mainviewcontroller class:

```
-(void) loadMapView {
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:mapViewController  animated:YES];
NSLog(@"loadMapView method is called!");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating a new `MainViewController` and sending your `-loadMapView` message to that, rather than any existing `MainViewController` in the navigation stack. Hence, `[self navigationController]` in that method is nil and the `-pushViewController:animated:` method is a no-op.

Comment: That i did understand, but do you also know how i do actually call a method in an active view controller without allocating it newly? I thought class methods were meant for this sort of actions, but class methods can't call local instance variables like the viewcontroller to push onto the stack.

Comment: I too am saddened that this answer did not include an instance of how to resolve the issue, but appreciate that you articulated what the problem is caused by.  @BTZ, did you ever figure out how to solve this?  I'm running into it from a viewcontroller within a view controller, myself, where I want to push a view but it's not working from within the contained viewcontroller.  Using super also didn't work.

Comment: Instead of calling `[mvcC loadMapView]` from the `ScrollViewController`, just call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvcC animated:YES]`.